# Can I apply concrete over tile mortar on a wall?

Tags: concrete, walls, removal, thinset

I am renovating a bathroom in a concrete structure. The bathroom had tiles on the walls (all now removed), but the amount of thinset used on two of the walls is kinda ridiculous. I have been able to remove some of it using a rotary hammer drill but there is still a lot (a lot) left.

The final finish will be concrete with a sealer - I like that bare concrete look. I am wondering if I can just concrete over the remaining thinset instead of removing it. Given that the final coat will be concrete anyway, and even the if the wall were completely smooth I would be putting a new 'skim' of concrete, so it seems like a plausible solution? I am quite new to this stuff, so I probably missing some critical info, but grateful for any input.

Thanks.

Comment: Concrete has gravel in it - you can't "skim" coat with concrete. Perhaps you're referring to a cement mortar instead?

Comment: Hey there - I appreciate your response. All of the things I have been reading on this finish refer to them as concrete:

https://civiljungle.com/concrete-finishing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can apply concrete or cement or stucco over the thinset. Some years ago the company I worked for sometimes put thinset down over old concrete decks prior to applying a final coating of cooldeck. ( a pool deck coating that stayed cool in the sun) The thinset added adhesion.

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful info. I am going to take some to ensure I get every single bit of the loose thinset off as a precaution. I appreciate you taking the time to respond.